# I changed my root document folder to use a subdirectory but its not working

Tags: .htaccess

what I want to achieve is my domain.com will use the subdirectory /new as the root document folder but when I tried visiting the site it redirects me to domain.com/new which is not what I want

the script was working before, but after i edit the script to use a different folder it doesn't work as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !new/
RewriteRule (.*) /new/$1 [L]
```

it redirects me to domain.com/new. i dont want /new to be shown in the url. thank you in advance!

Comment: Those lines will _not_ redirect your client. There is no redirection implemented in there. Most likely it is your application logic that wrongly uses absolute paths in references it creates. So that is what you need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules with this rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /new/
```